# Estimate the color distribution by Guassian mixture model

Tags: matlab, gaussian, image-segmentation, estimation, mixture-model

I have an Image and i want to estimate the color distribution of the input image by a Gaussian Mixture Model, how i can do it with Matlab?

```
myImage = imread('Jellyfish.jpg');
```

`gmdistribution.fit(X,k)` is not work for me, because X must be a 2D Matrix and myImage is 3D Matrix, i get this error when use `gmdistribution.fit(myImage,10)`:
X must be a numeric 2-D matrix.

when i use `gmdistribution.fit(myImage(:,:,1),10)` for Red color of Image i get this error:

```
Error using var (line 59)
First argument must be single or double.

Error in gmdistribution.fit (line 133)
varX = var(X);
```

and when i use :  `gmdistribution.fit(single(myImage(:,:,1)),10)` i give this error:

```
Error using gmcluster (line 180)
Ill-conditioned covariance created at iteration 2.

Error in gmdistribution.fit (line 174)
    [S,NlogL,optimInfo] =...
```

i want to use this for an Image Segmentation using Gaussian Mixture Models. if you have any idea, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it like this

```
gmdistribution.fit(single(myImage(:,:,1)),10)
```

The point is that by default RGB image is loaded as array of integer elements. You're said that this function cannot accept integer elements - it need single of double(floating point data types). You can do this by explicit type conversion.

Comment: i get this error : Error using gmcluster (line 180)
Ill-conditioned covariance created at iteration 2.

Comment: Well, that, I suppose, problem of your data. A matrix is ill-conditioned if the condition number is too large (and singular if it is infinite). You can read more about conditional number here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number